# Android: Play next cued video in onVideoEnd()

Tags: java, android, class, video, youtube

I have a Youtube player within my app. I have set a setPlayerStateChangeListener for this player, and on the event of the video ending (onVideoEnd()) I wish to play the next cued video.

This is what I have so far...

**YouTubeFragment**

```
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean restored) {
    ...
    player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(myPlayerStateChangeListener);
    ...
}
```

**MyPlayerStateChangeListener**

```
package x;

import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;

public final class MyPlayerStateChangeListener implements YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener {


    @Override
    public void onAdStarted() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(
            com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaded(String arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoading() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoEnded() {
        Log.d("onVideoEnded()", "Video has ended");
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoStarted() {
    }
}
```

When the video ends, the log message within onVideoEnded() successfully displays. What I am struggling to get my head around is how I can run hasNext(), play() etc on my youtube player from within this PlayerStateChangeListener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can use the following :

```
private static YouTubePlayer player;
```

In onInitializationSuccess() set this variable.

```
this.player = player;
```

Now in the callback onVideoEnd() use the static version of the player to perform the actions that you need like cueing a new video.

Comment: thanks for the answer. any chance you could expand your answer in code form?

Comment: where am I adding the first line off code? before onInitializationSucess()?

Comment: also how do I use the static version of the player in onVideoEnd()?

Comment: the first line goes into the class where you are doing the youtube player initialization, it is a class variable.

Comment: static usage would be ClassName.player.cueVideo(vid-url);